# Trying to use jQuery to filter Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm on the right track, but I just can't get this to work.

I'm using an inline javascript call with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( 'a.sort' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
toSort = $( this ).data( 'type' );
$( '.common-li-class' ).not( toSort ).hide();
} );
</script>
```

And then adding class="common man" or class="common woman", etc.. to my li's

Lastly, I added links to trigger these with:

```
    <a class="sort" data-type="man" href="#">Men</a>
    <a class="sort" data-type="woman" href="#">Women</a>
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Try `.not('[data-type='+toSort+']')`

Answer (score 0):

The script that you had used would evaluate the selector as `$('.common-li-class').not('man').hide();` But as per the html reference you had given `man` is a class, so we have to prefix it with dot in order to make that selector valid.

Try,

```
$('.common-li-class').not('.' + toSort).hide();
```

Comment: Hmm.  I tried this, but it still appears to not be doing anything.

Comment: @user3720998 can you make a demo in jsfiddle.net ..?

Comment: @user3720998 Are you looking for something like this.? http://jsfiddle.net/3LAHJ/3/   and let me know if this satisfied your need .. :)

Comment: Yes!  Exactly.  I'm not sure whats different with your code and mine.  LOL

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried copying your js back into my original file, and it still doesn't seem to like it, as it does in your example.  :(

Comment: @rizarjay please have a look at this part in your live site, `<li class="common man">` .. Are the same as we used in that fiddle..?

Comment: I simplified it a bit for the fiddle, but there should be no functional difference.

Comment: Is your site live..? can I have a look at it now..?

Comment: @rizarjay have you noticed the error in the console..? Jquery library is not getting loaded properly.. :(

Comment: Hmm. Really?  My slider seems to work just fine, and that uses jquery?

Comment: Is script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"  /script not enough?

Comment: @rizarjay I think some kind of conflicting is happening.. try to remove that slider codes and just use the code written by us.. So that we can figure out which block of the code is making trouble..

Comment: OK.  I commented the slider stuff out.  Now what I'm noticing is that the trigger links are sending me to the top of the page, but I thought the preventDefault line was supposed to cancel that, so you're probably right in that it's doing something fishy.

Comment: Hmm. Commented out all my CSS and still not working.

Comment: I wanted to get my site back to "working" the way it was before I started playing with it, so I moved my modified version to www.ngcwrestling.com/wrestlers2.html so you can look at it, if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3LAHJ), it just seems like you had the wrong selector for selecting the list items that you are trying to filter. You have `.common-li-class` when all you need is `.common` or `li.common`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.sort').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   toSort = $( this).data('type');
   $('.common').not('.' + toSort).hide();
} );
</script>
```

Comment: @rizarjay, if you're using jsfiddle, you need to load the jQuery library from the left sidebar. The library must also be one that supports the `on()` function. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PTGLj/